# How to store user object and use user in all components after login using angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

1. I created a login page.when user is logged,a request sent to server
   side and token is obtained in response.
2. I am storing this token in local storage.using this token,i am
   sending a request to server side and retrieving the user json data
   in response.
3. Now my main aim is to store the user object and use this object in all components.for example: In Dashboard page and some other places.
4. Tell me where to store the user object and how to use it

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it in localstorage and provide a shared service that reads it from localstorage on request, or store it in the service itself.

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: can you give me example in two ways

Comment: There are about 100 similar questions and the doc should it explain quite well (except the access to localstorage but that doesn't seem to be the core of the question anyway)

Comment: But isn't that insecure since it possible to modify local storage value from using Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: @devN not sure what kind of "secure" you mean. If it's in the browser it's always the same kind of secure/insecure.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer for the app I am currently working on, we are using some `id`'s which  is stored in localstorage and then used to pass to API call and retrieve data. If user is able to change this `id` value which is stored in localstorage, he would be able to access another user's data. How to avoid this?

Comment: There is nothing you can do on the client, you need to ensure on the server that a user can't access other users data. If you do this on the client side only, then there is no security at all.